# Unable to send records back from Lambda to kinesis firehose delivery stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I've attached a lambda function to my kinesis firehose delivery stream to transform the record as per my requirement. But the error i get is this:-

```
The Lambda function was successfully invoked but it returned an error result.
```

Here is what it logs in the error/ prefix of my s3 bucket the json reads as follows:-

```
{
"attemptsMade":4,
"arrivalTimestamp":1673595303311,
"errorCode":"Lambda.FunctionError",
"errorMessage":"The Lambda function was successfully invoked but it returned an error result.",
"attemptEndingTimestamp":1673595379712,
"rawData":"eyJkZXZpY2VfbmFtZSI6ImluSGFuZC1SVFUiLCJUZW1wZXJhdHVyZSI6MjQsIlB5cmFub21ldGVyIjoxMiwiQWN0aXZlLVBvd2VyIjowLCJWb2x0YWdlLTEiOjI0MC4wNjk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OSwiQWN0aXZlLUltcG9ydCI6Mi41Njk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk4LCJ0aW1lIjoxNjczNTk1MzAzMjMxfQo="
}
```

Here is my lambda code:-

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const output = event.records.map((rcord) => {
        const firehose_stream_data = Buffer.from(rcord.data,'base64').toString();
        const records = JSON.parse(firehose_stream_data);
        let {time} = records;
        let timestamp = new Date(new Date(time).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }));
        let date = timestamp.getDate();
        let month = timestamp.getMonth() + 1;
        month = ( month < 10 ? '0' + month : month);
        let year = timestamp.getFullYear();
        let hour = (timestamp.getHours() <= 9) ? '0' + timestamp.getHours() : timestamp.getHours();
        let minute = (timestamp.getMinutes() <= 9) ? '0' + timestamp.getMinutes() : timestamp.getMinutes();
        let second = (timestamp.getSeconds() <= 9) ? '0' + timestamp.getSeconds() : timestamp.getSeconds();
        let finalTimestamp = date + "-" + month + "-" + year+ " " +hour+":" +minute+":"+second;
        const finalRecord = JSON.stringify({
                ...records,
                time : finalTimestamp,
        });
        const partitionKeys = {site_name:records.device_name,year:year,month:month,day:date};
        
        return {
            recordId : rcord.recordId,
            result: 'Ok',
            data: (Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(finalRecord))).toString('base64'),
            metadata : {partitionKeys: partitionKeys}
        };
     
        /* This transformation is the "identity" transformation, the data is left intact */
        // recordId: record.recordId,
        // result: 'Ok',
        // data: record.data,
        
    });
    // console.log(`Processing completed.  Successful records ${output.length}.`);
    // return { records: output };
};
```

The permission which lambda has are:-

```
Allow: kinesis:PutRecords & basic lambda execution role
```

I basically convert the epoch in milliseconds to a proper timestamp, I also want to send the partition keys along with the payload to use partitionKeyFromLambda to parition data in IST time like:-

```
site_name=<name>/year=2023/month=01/day=13/<files>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check cloudwatch logs for the actual error messages?

Comment: The lambda functions executes fine, here is what it says inside my firehose delivery stream log {
    "deliveryStreamVersionId": 3,
    "message": "The Lambda function was successfully invoked but it returned an error result.",
    "errorCode": "Lambda.FunctionError",
}

Comment: I've put the error log in the question itself for better readability of the error

Comment: This does not seem to be error from cloudwatch logs. Did you check the CW logs for the function?

Comment: Yes i did, for both aws lambda function and firehose delivery stream under "DestinationDelivery"" , the error i have posted in the question is from the file firehose logged under the errors/ prefix in my s3 bucket